# Active Tag in for extended templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a newbie to Django and want some help on template inheritance.
 I want to set "class="active" for the current active page but how do I do with template inheritance,as it generalizes it for all the pages but the active should change on changing current active page.
I know this question might be silly but I don't know the answer still.

I have no idea what to do for this case.

**Extended html**

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
    <a class="nav-link" {% if '/Homepage/' in request.path %} class ="active" {% endif %} href="{% url 'success' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
    <a class="nav-link" {% if '/booking/' in request.path %} class ="active" {% endif %} href="{% url 'booking' %}">Make a Booking</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
    <a class="nav-link" {% if '/Hsitory/' in request.path %} class ="active" {% endif %} href="{% url 'History' %}">History</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mx-3">
    <a class="nav-link" {% if '/pending/' in request.get_full_path %} class ="active" {% endif %} href="{% url 'pending' %}">Pending requests</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.loginpage, name="loginpage"),
path("failed/", views.failed, name="failed"),
path("Homepage/", views.success, name="success"),
path("loggedout/", views.loggedout, name="logout"),
path("booking/", views.booking, name="booking"),
path("pending/", views.pending, name="pending"),
path("History/", views.History, name="History"),
path("Register/", views.Register, name="Register"),
]
```

I expect the active class might get applied to only current active pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
<a class="nav-link" {% if '/Homepage/' in request.path %} class ="active" {% endif %} href="/Homepage/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Also better use the django url template [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

EDIT: I think you are providing wrong url patterns 
You can also do this

```
{% url 'homepage' as url %}
<a {% if request.path == url %} class="active"{% endif %} href="{{ url }}" >Homepage</a>
```

You have two class attribute in your anchor tag so you can change this to

```
 <a class="nav-link{% if request.path == url %} active{% endif %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Comment: I replaced that anchor tag but nothing happened !! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Dev you need to do that for every pages you want to have

Comment: I have edited the question code as you said, but it still don't work, i will edit question.

Comment: @Dev can you show your urls as well and check my updated answer

Comment: just give me 5 mins I'll do it

Comment: I checked printing something in 'if' case and went well, i think the jinja format in anchor tag doesn't work.

Comment: Your Post helped me solve the problem!!I appreciate your help , I am posting the solution if you think its not that good please do tell me to correct it.

Comment: @Dev yes it was the problem with anchor tag.check my answer

Comment: I tried that updated answer but is also doesn't work inside the class

Comment: Last answer did worked , I mistakenly added wrong url

Answer (score 0):

**Extended Html**

```
<li class="nav-item mx-3">
      {% url 'success' as Homepage %}
      {% if request.path != Homepage %} <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'success' %}">Home <span
          class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ Homepage }}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mx-3">
      {% url 'booking' as booking %}
      {% if request.path != booking %} <a class="nav-link" href="{{ booking }}">Make a Booking</a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ booking }}">Make a Booking</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mx-3">
      {% url 'History' as History %}
      {% if request.path != History %} <a class="nav-link" href="{{ History }}">History</a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="nav-link active" href="{{ History }}">History</a>
      {% endif %}

    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mx-3">
      {% url 'pending' as pending %}
      {% if request.path != pending %} <a class="nav-link" href="{{ pending }}">Pending requests</a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <a class="nav-link active " href="{{ pending }}">Pending requests</a>
    {% endif %}

    </li>
```

> Used request.path for the solution